# Finding homomorphisms of $S_n$ → C* and $A_n$ → C*

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My idea was to use the homomorphism theorem for [$S_n$,$S_n$] as for any f:$S_n$ → C* by setting N=[$S_n$,$S_n$] we know that there is exacly one g:$S_n$/[$S_n$,$S_n$] → C*

However we know that $S_n$/[$S_n$,$S_n$]=$S_n$/$A_n$, but $S_n$/$A_n$ ≅ Z/2Z

Therefore there is exacly one g:Z/2Z → C*
so all elements of a ∈ C* give us ord(a)|g[Z/2Z]
so a can only be -1 or 1.

Now we know that f:$S_n$ → {-1,1}

Aaaaand I'm stuck. :/

Comment: Hint: send everything in $A_n$ to $1$. Where do you think everything else must go? Your instincts were correct, $\Bbb C^{\ast}$ is abelian, and $S_n$ is not (unless $n < 3$) so your homomorphism must factor through the commutator projection.