# $f: S_n \to Z$ where $S_n$ is the set of permutations. $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$ in $S_n$, then $f$ is identical $0, 1,$ or signature function.

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

I need to prove the statement in the title:

> $f: S_n \to Z$ where $S_n$  is the set of permutations. $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for all $a,b$ in $S_n$,
>   then $f$ is identical $0, 1,$ or signature function. Prove and explain.

I don't want an answer but a hand on the question's explanation on what should I look for. I think $S_n$ is a group with operation of composition. Should I use the fact that f is a homomorphism? What does it have to do with the signature function.

Also does f being identical to 0, 1 or signature function means that f is identical to 0 function or identity function or signature function? I am kind of confused if you can help me I would be really grateful!

Comment: If $f$ takes the value zero, it's identically zero. Otherwise $f$ can only take values $\pm1$ and then $f:S_n\to\{\pm1\}$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: What is $Z$?...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Why does it can only take values of ±1, by which part that I see that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: S_n \to \mathbb C^*$ be a group homomorphism. Then $f$ is the signature function or $f$ is trivial:

Reference: [Finding all group homomorphisms of $S_n\to\mathbb{C}^*$ and $A_n\to\mathbb{C}^*$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763321/finding-all-group-homomorphisms-of-s-n-to-mathbbc-and-a-n-to-mathbbc)

In particular, every group homomorphism $f: S_n \to \Bbb Z$ is either trivial or the signature function. The idea is to use that $S_n$ is generated by transpositions.

Comment: Hmm, so if I understand correctly $a /in S_n$ then we can say that $a$ is made of transpositions equal to the number of inversions. Then since this is a homomorphism we can separate the inversions in the function. How do we get that the range can be either ±1?

Comment: This is explained in the answer by lhf, so we have $\tau^2=1$, hence $f(\tau)^2=f(\tau^2)=f(1)=1$. Hence $f(\tau)=\pm 1$.

Comment: I think this is because its a homomorphism and 1 should be mapped to 1 right? Thank you so much for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, $f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)\cdot f(1)$.