# What is the kernel of $h$ where $h:S_3 \to \mathbb{R}^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra

$S_3$ is the permutation group on 3 symbols and $\mathbb{R}^*$ denotes the multiplicative group of non zero real numbers under multiplication. $h: S_3 \to \mathbb{R}^* $is given a homomorphism. But I am unable to define the mapping. I don't know which mapping will make it a homomorphism. Only then I'll be able to find the kernel. What am I missing?
Please help.

Comment: That question is not entirely well-defined, There are at least two homomorphisms $S_3 \to \mathbb{R}^*$: (1) The trivial homomorphism, which sends everything to $1 \in \mathbb{R}^*$, and (2) the sign homomorphism, which assigns to each permutation $\sigma \in S_3$ its sign $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma) \in \{-1, 1\}$. Can you provide more context about the homomorphism $h$?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763321/finding-all-group-homomorphisms-of-s-n-to-mathbbc-and-a-n-to-mathbbc

Answer (score 6):

The imagine of $S_3$ must be a subgroup of $\Bbb R ^*$ of order a divisor of 6. So, if $x\in h(S_3)$ $x^6=1\implies x=\pm 1$. Now we have two possibilities: $h(S_3)=\{1\}$ or $h(S_3)=\{\pm 1\}$. In the first case the kernel is all the group, in the second it must be a subgroup of $S_3$ of index 2, so it must be $A_3$.

Comment: Why is image of S3 subgroup of order a divisor if 6

Comment: @user686123 because $S_3/Kerh\equiv h(S_3)$ and you can pass at cardinalities

Answer (score 0):

If $h: S_3 \to R^*$ is a homomorphism, then $S_3/\textrm{kern}(h) \cong h(S^3) \subseteq R^*$. For $\sigma, \tau \in S^3$, we would then have $$h(\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1} \tau^{-1}) = h(\sigma) h(\tau) h(\sigma^{-1}) h( \tau^{-1}) = h(\sigma) h(\tau) h(\sigma)^{-1} h( \tau)^{-1} = 1$$ by the commutativity of $R^*$. Therefore $\textrm{kern(h)}$ contains the commutator subgroup of $S_3$. This subgroup happens to be the cyclic group generated by $(1\;2\;3)$. By lagrange's theorem, since the order of $\textrm{kern(h)}$ is at least 3, we have that $|h(S_3)| \leq 2$ which leaves few options for $h$.